# Jinja2 if statement in vs equals on dict

Tags: python, if-statement, jinja2

I'm new to Jinja2 and using it as part of Flask.  I've got two statements below.  The one with "in" works.  The one with "equals" isn't.  The equals version is getting a syntax error shown below.  I'm curious as to why, as the way the equals version is written, to me at least, is easier to read.

```
{% if "SN" in P01["type"] %}
  {% include 'sn.html' %}
{% endif %}

{% if P01["type"] equals "SN" %}
  {% include 'sn.html' %}
{% endif %}
```

The errors message from jinja2.exceptions.TemplateSyntaxError

> TemplateSyntaxError: expected token 'end of statement block', got 'equals'

Thank you.

Comment: And `do what I want` is arguably even easier to read. That doesn't mean it should (or can) work. Are you seriously asking "why doesn't Jinja implement this syntax"? Because that question is unlikely to survive, partly because it's hard to actually answer without summoning Armin Ronacher.

Comment: I'm trying to learn.  I'm not trying to say it should or shouldn't.  I just don't understand.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

In Jinja2 you would use `==` instead of `equals`, for example:

```
{% if P01["type"] == "SN" %}
  {% include 'sn.html' %}
{% endif %}
```

http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/switching/#conditions

I'm pretty sure this is what you are looking for, but you should note that this has a different meaning than `"SN" in P01["type"]`, using `in` is a substring test, so for example `"foo" in "foobar"` would be True.

Comment: Thank you FJ.  This is what I'm looking for.  I must be following an old tutorial or example on template language as I had only seen the "equals" word used.